# Variable ID is undefined

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

Can anyone review this code and tell me why I am getting variable ID undefined error?

```
<cffunction name="login" access="public" returntype="void">
  <cfargument name="rc" type="struct" required="true">
  <cfset user = getUserService().login(arguments.rc.Username,arguments.rc.password)>
  <cfif isDefined('User')>
    <cfset session.auth = structNew()>
    <cfset session.auth.isLoggedin = "yes"/>
    <cfset session.auth.user = user />
    <cfset session.auth.id = id>  
    <cfset session.auth.username = UserName />
    <cfset session.auth.password = password />
  <cfelse>
    <cfset rc.message = createMessage('error','','entered password is wrong')>
    <cfset variables.fw.redirect('login.default','message')>
  </cfif>
  <cfset variables.fw.redirect('')>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Because the id variable on the <cfset session.auth.id = id> line doesn't exist in the variables, form, or URL scope. Where are you defining that value? Should it be user.id?

Comment: yeah it is in user.id.

Comment: Have you tested this in Coldfusion 9 and Coldfusion 10. If you have then please say so in the question, otherwise please pick a Coldfusion version that your having the problem on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly scope your variable (as I stated in my comment). Change `= id` to `= user.id`

Comment: @sulemankhan - If you found their response helpful, feel free to upvote it. :)

Answer (score 5):

You will save yourself (and other future devs) a lot of headaches by scoping your variables.

```
<cfset session.auth.id = User.id>
```

If User is a query or struct then you can also reference your record with dot notation

```
<cfset session.auth.id = User.id[1]>
```

Comment: "save yourself (and other future devs) a lot of headaches by scoping your variables." - So true

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are defining ID. If you don't define it before you try to access it, you will get an error.

```
<cfset session.auth.id = id>
```